# Delete row from table once user click on Add to cart

Tags: magento-1.9

When user remove the Previously added item from cart, than it will be removed from Database table : **sales_flat_quote_item_option**, i need similar feature.

**Question** : once Registered user click on custom button "**save design**" in [product view page](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/custom-apple-iphone-4.html#) , we are creating new row in **my_designs** table and creating new product and saving product information in database.

[image]

once customer click on "**add to cart**" for that product, we want to remove that product information from "**my_designs**" table. we want to delete that row.

[image]

we are using below code to add the product to cart

```
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>

<?php $collections = $this->getCollection(); ?>

<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>

<div id="messages_product_view">
<?php $buttonTitle = Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Add to Cart')); ?>
</div>

<?php foreach ($collections as $key => $product) {

    echo $product->getName().' <br>';
?>
<form action="<?php echo  Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($product);?>" method="post">  
<div class="add-to-cart-buttons">

<button type="submit" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" class="button btn-cart" >
    <span><span>
    <?php echo $buttonTitle ?>
    </span></span>
</button>

<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true) ?>

</div>
</form>
<hr style='display:inline-block; width:100%;'>
<?php

}
?>
```

Comment: what is this Vikas. why you  Always going with bounty??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create an observer in your code **config.xml**

```
<frontend>
    ........
    <events>
        <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
            <observers>
                <delete_save_design_row>
                    <class>Amasty_Example_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>_deletedesign</method>
                </delete_save_design_row>
            </observers>
        </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
    </events>
    .........
</frontend>
```

Now create a new file **Amasty/Example/Model/Observer.php** with below code

```
<?php

class Amasty_Example_Model_Observer
{
    public function _deletedesign($observer)
    { 
        $productId = $observer->getProduct()->getId();
        $customerId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId();
        $collection = Mage::getModel('example/mydesign')->getCollection()
                ->addFieldToFilter('product_id', $productId)
                ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customerId);
        $collection->walk("delete");
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: As in Db table also, i gave name as `product_id & customer_id` , in observer.php, i am trying as `->addFieldToFilter('product_id', 'product_id')
                ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', 'customer_id');` , full code : http://pastebin.com/QEhj3SN7 , but i am getting this error : `Fatal error: Call to a member function addFieldToFilter() on a non-object in line 10` , what wrong i done here?....

Comment: Use observer from my code as it is. It will work.

Comment: yes, i trust you more than me :) but i faced same error.....

Comment: Check with updated observer code.

Comment: i got error as can not add the item to shopping cart` :  http://prnt.sc/eongua

Comment: The issue seems to be related to add to cart functionality.

Comment: yes, you are right, i tried deleting observer code, now add to cart is working......

Comment: Please check with updated code

Comment: yes, seems nothing is impossible for you.... worked absolutely fine, Thanks for your golden time....

Answer (score 2):

use `controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_cart_add` event refer [link](http://inchoo.net/magento/dispatching-before-and-after-events-to-magento-core-actions/)

get **`product id` from param** and **`customer id` from session**

use above **both id to delete entry** from your table

**UPDATE** Query to delete entry

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('amasty/mydesign_collection')
        ->addFieldToFilter('product_id', <YOUR_PRODUCT_ID)
        ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', <CUSTOMER_ID);
$collection->walk("delete");
```

Comment: Thanks, i will try , if you can update an answer with some code that will be really helpfull.....

Comment: You have not provided name and model of database from which you want to remove entry @BabyinMagento

Comment: please check : http://prnt.sc/eoavvd & here is `app/code/local/Amasty/Example/Model/Mysql4/Amasty/collection.php` - http://pastebin.com/aLrf1ASY

Comment: Find updated answer @BabyinMagento

Comment: Thanks a lot for updating with code, you can see our database table structure in question, so i am using your code in same file : http://pastebin.com/0CyrUGqK please check and tell me is there anything else i need to do ?

Comment: No use this code in the observer

Comment: with help of google, i created new function & added your code here : app/code/local/Amasty/Example/Model/Observer.php = http://pastebin.com/j6ge61gn . also this is modules config.xml file , where i need to add observer code here : http://pastebin.com/UuNfQL9v

Answer (score 1):

You can use a trigger for that :

```
CREATE TRIGGER deleteDesign
    ON sales_flat_quote_item
    FOR DELETE
AS
    DELETE FROM my_designs
    WHERE product_id = (SELECT deleted.id FROM deleted) AND customer_id = (SELECT deleted.customer_id FROM deleted)
GO
```

When an item is removed from *sales_flat_quote_item* table, it will delete it from *my_designs*.

Comment: Thanks a lot , i already got solution, so  i opened bounty to award the very good answer, i will still try your answer and let you know......